# Centering button on extra small screen Material-UI React not working (justify-xs-center)

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, material-ui, react-component

I tried everything but it seems that I'm missing something. I have been trying a lot of time to make a button center inside the grid when the screen is extra small.

This code works perfectly, but the problem is that i want my button to only center when the screen is extra small not on all sizes.

Working Code.

```
Grid item xs={12}>
  <Grid container justify="center">
    <Button color="primary" variant="raised">
      Add Product
    </Button>
  </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

Not working code...

```
Grid item xs={12}>
  <Grid container className={"justify-xs-center"}>
    <Button color="primary" variant="raised">
      Add Product
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I have been reading the API documentation for the Grid, as i understand this is the correct way to add a predefined class in the component, but the effect seems not to work. When i inspect the element though the class justify-xs-center is found on the Grid container component as expected.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: give the parent container which contains your button a width, maybe 100%, then set margin-left: "auto" and margin-right: "auto" so the contents inside are centered. inspecting your html elements will also help get some context as to why flex isn't working

Comment: Thank you friend, i was just assuming something wrong for the CSS API of material-ui

Comment: not an uncommon thought, but most of the time in these cases highly unlikely. cheers buddy

Comment: I found myself in a similar situation and what i expected
What i hoped for was something like `justify-xs-center` plus `justify-sm-flex-start`,  but there’s no such thing :(
It seems like we need to write the media queries

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems i have really misunderstood the CSS API of the Grid.
https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#css-api

My solution to this was to use the breakpoints offered by material-ui.
https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#theme-breakpoints-up-key-media-query

I created this CSS rule and applied it to the Grid container element that i wanted its contents to be centered.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  addButtonContainer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      justifyContent: "center"
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the container that is being centered on extra small screens

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <Grid container className={classes.addButtonContainer}>
    <Button color="primary" variant="raised">
      Add Product
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```